# How to list the users under login as a service local security policy using power-shell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want find users under the login as a service policy using Power shell. I don't want to use the any third party dll or modules to achieve this.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions and edit the question accordingly. As of now, it's just a [problem statement](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/).

Comment: sure i will read and change as per guidelines

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want something like this:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0

Example use:

```
Get-AccountsWithUserRight -Right SeServiceLogonRight
```

```
function Get-AccountsWithUserRight {
 <#
  .SYNOPSIS
    Gets all accounts that are assigned a specified privilege
  .DESCRIPTION
    Retrieves a list of all accounts that hold a specified right (privilege). The accounts returned are those that hold the specified privilege directly through the user account, not as part of membership to a group. A list of SIDs and account names is returned. For each SID that cannot be resolved to a name, the Account property is set to an empty string ("").
  .PARAMETER Right
    Name of the right to query. More than one right may be listed.

    Possible values: 
      SeTrustedCredManAccessPrivilege              Access Credential Manager as a trusted caller
      SeNetworkLogonRight                          Access this computer from the network
      SeTcbPrivilege                               Act as part of the operating system
      SeMachineAccountPrivilege                    Add workstations to domain
      SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege                     Adjust memory quotas for a process
      SeInteractiveLogonRight                      Allow log on locally
      SeRemoteInteractiveLogonRight                Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services
      SeBackupPrivilege                            Back up files and directories
      SeChangeNotifyPrivilege                      Bypass traverse checking
      SeSystemtimePrivilege                        Change the system time
      SeTimeZonePrivilege                          Change the time zone
      SeCreatePagefilePrivilege                    Create a pagefile
      SeCreateTokenPrivilege                       Create a token object
      SeCreateGlobalPrivilege                      Create global objects
      SeCreatePermanentPrivilege                   Create permanent shared objects
      SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege                Create symbolic links
      SeDebugPrivilege                             Debug programs
      SeDenyNetworkLogonRight                      Deny access this computer from the network
      SeDenyBatchLogonRight                        Deny log on as a batch job
      SeDenyServiceLogonRight                      Deny log on as a service
      SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight                  Deny log on locally
      SeDenyRemoteInteractiveLogonRight            Deny log on through Remote Desktop Services
      SeEnableDelegationPrivilege                  Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation
      SeRemoteShutdownPrivilege                    Force shutdown from a remote system
      SeAuditPrivilege                             Generate security audits
      SeImpersonatePrivilege                       Impersonate a client after authentication
      SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege                Increase a process working set
      SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege              Increase scheduling priority
      SeLoadDriverPrivilege                        Load and unload device drivers
      SeLockMemoryPrivilege                        Lock pages in memory
      SeBatchLogonRight                            Log on as a batch job
      SeServiceLogonRight                          Log on as a service
      SeSecurityPrivilege                          Manage auditing and security log
      SeRelabelPrivilege                           Modify an object label
      SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege                 Modify firmware environment values
      SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege    Obtain an impersonation token for another user in the same session
      SeManageVolumePrivilege                      Perform volume maintenance tasks
      SeProfileSingleProcessPrivilege              Profile single process
      SeSystemProfilePrivilege                     Profile system performance
      SeUnsolicitedInputPrivilege                  "Read unsolicited input from a terminal device"
      SeUndockPrivilege                            Remove computer from docking station
      SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege                Replace a process level token
      SeRestorePrivilege                           Restore files and directories
      SeShutdownPrivilege                          Shut down the system
      SeSyncAgentPrivilege                         Synchronize directory service data
      SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege                     Take ownership of files or other objects
  .PARAMETER Computer
    Specifies the name of the computer on which to run this cmdlet. If the input for this parameter is omitted, then the cmdlet runs on the local computer.
  .PARAMETER SidForUnresolvedName
    For each SID that cannot be resolved to a name, set the Account property to the SID instead of leaving it blank.
  .EXAMPLE
    Get-AccountsWithUserRight SeServiceLogonRight

    Returns a list of all accounts that hold the "Log on as a service" right.
  .EXAMPLE
    Get-AccountsWithUserRight -Right SeServiceLogonRight,SeDebugPrivilege -Computer TESTPC

    Returns a list of accounts that hold the "Log on as a service" right, and a list of accounts that hold the "Debug programs" right, on the TESTPC system.
  .INPUTS
    PS_LSA.Rights Right
    String Computer
    Switch SidForUnresolvedName
  .OUTPUTS
    String Account
    String SID
    String Right
  .LINK
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms721792.aspx
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530716.aspx
 #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [Alias('Privilege')] [PS_LSA.Rights[]] $Right,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, HelpMessage="Computer name")]
        [Alias('System','ComputerName','Host')][String] $Computer,
        [switch] $SidForUnresolvedName
    )
    process {
        $lsa = New-Object PS_LSA.LsaWrapper($Computer)
        foreach ($Priv in $Right) {
            $sids = $lsa.EnumerateAccountsWithUserRight($Priv, $false)
            foreach ($sid in $sids) {
                $output = @{'Account'=(Convert-SIDtoName $sid $SidForUnresolvedName); 'SID'=$sid; 'Right'=$Priv; }
                Write-Output (New-Object -Typename PSObject -Prop $output)
            }
        }
    }
} # Gets all accounts that are assigned specified rights
```